# HTTP Error 500 When I put my website link in href

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, permalinks

I have a self hosted WordPress 4.9.9 website on Apache server.
Recently I can't access any page in the site which has a hyperlink with an href attribute with the value of my website link.

For example: when a page contains a link like 
the page returns HTTP Error 500 and when I remove the link everything works well.

Another problem, I can't access any post when using mywebsite.com/?p=11 for example.
I tried to reset my permalink structure and it doesn't work.

Finally, I tried using filters like (the_permalink) and other similar filters and it works perfectly.

As a last attempt, I copied all website's files and database and put them all in another subdomain, and it works perfectly.

My current permalink structure is %category%post_name and changing it doesn't resolve the problem.

Versions used: WP 4.9.9 - PHP 7.2.6

How can I fix the problem on the main domain ?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use absolute or relative URLs to your site in your href?

Comment: Did you make sure to copy hidden files like .htaccess and such? If not there may be a difference between the original and the copy that's causing the problem.

Comment: after applying the filters all permalinks become relative (ex: /products/product1 ) but when I put the absolute url ( ex: https://mywebsite.com/product/product1 ) the error appears.

Comment: @J.T.Blum yes, I copied all files including the .htaccess file

Comment: Your Apache and PHP logs will tell you exactly what the problem is.  What do they say?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Unfortunately, I have no access to Apache and PHP logs since I am using shared hosting

Comment: I would be surprised if that is true - shared hosting usually offers access to your logs.  Ask your provider, check your web admin or whatever you use.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I have only the php error log and it doesn't show anything except some unrelated notices and warnings. My shared hosting does not provide access to the server error log.